# Error : unrecognize fontfamily ionicons react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i have this error in react-native run-ios 
:
Error : unrecognize fontfamily ionicons react native

Comment: have you added the extra fonts into the react native application ?

Comment: please share some code what you did.

Comment: yes i added my fonts to react native project

Comment: Have you read [this issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/72)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the react native does not have that font Family, for custom fonts you need to add it yourself, here is the link, hope this will help :
https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked it using `react-native link` ?